# A point such that Areas of triangle formed is equal to area of given quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math

'**ABCD is a quadrilateral and X is a given Point in AD. Find a point Y in AB such that the area of triangle AXY is equal to that of ABCD**'

Since it is a quadrilateral, I haven't reached anywhere using Congruency or similarity. For the same reason, I also have difficulty applying Melanus's theoem or Ceva's theorem.

Considering the question is among the first 10 questions of the exercise, it shouldn't be that complicated and thus I would be grateful if someone could point out what I am missing.

Comment: Just our quadrilateral is not convex.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Otherwise it's impossible that area of $AXY$ is equal to the area $ABCD$.

Comment: Is $X$ on segment $AB$ or line $AB$?

Comment: X lies on the line segment AD. While it is not mentioned that Y lies on line AB, it would be best to assume so. If Y lies on line segment AB then the quadrilateral must be concave, however it is not mentioned in the question that the quadrilateral is concave therefore I think that the procedure of finding the point Y must be applicable for both concave and convex quadrilaterals.

Comment: It seems that there are more than one solution.

Comment: I still can't solve it, any hint would be appreciated

Comment: I've just answered the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753304/making-the-area-of-the-quadrilateral-and-the-area-of-a-triangle-the-same/3757013#3757013